# Currency validation and formatting using single function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to validate and format currency values from a single function. It gives alert for empty value also. Can anyone help me out for a better solution?

```
$('.currency').blur(function() {
var formatted = parseFloat($(this).val());
if(formatted) {
formatted = formatted.toFixed(2);
$(this).val(formatted);
}else{
if(formatted != "") {alert('Invalid Amount....!!!');} }
});
```

Comment: Required currency format is 6500.90, 650.09, 40.00 etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var formatted = parseFloat($(this).val());
```

Will set `formatted` to `NaN` if the input value is empty. You're then testing `formatted` in an `if` statement. `NaN` is "false-y" which means you will get the `alert`.

What do you want to do in case of an empty value? If you want to ignore it, treat it as 0:

```
var value = $(this).val();
value = (value.trim() === "" ? "0" : value);
```

You might also want to check if `formatted` is `NaN` instead:

```
if(!isNaN(formatted)) {
    //valid value
} else {
    //invalid value
}
```